# The images show on frontend pagespeed.ic._LOWhFVaw2.webp after image filename

Tags: magento2.3, media-images, not-showing

**For example the images address on frontend website show this:**
https://takoda.shop/pub/media/logo/default/170xNxTakoda_met_Tijger_O_logo_kleuren_nieuw.png.pagespeed.ic._LOWhFVaw2.webp

**It adds at the end:** pagespeed.ic._LOWhFVaw2.webp

Never consciously changed anything by purpose

This causes possibly that some images **on mobile view are not showing**

**Now also not in the browser look:**
[image]

That is probably the reason

> Only how to turn that off or fix this?

You find on google that it could be google pagespeed module, this module is not in the config.php file

> Anyone got any clue what this could be and how to turn it off?

*It can conflict with lazy load*

**The frontend is:**
[www.takoda.shop](https://www.takoda.shop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The images are being automatically optimised by the pagespeed module

> The PageSpeed Modules, **mod_pagespeed** and **ngx_pagespeed**, are open-source webserver modules that optimize your site automatically.

To confirm this load your site with the `?PageSpeed=off` switch at the end of the url, this will manually disable pagespeed for that url.

This means you have installed the pagespeed module on your apache / niginx web service and have enabled the image optimsation options.

You should check your server configuration and pagespeed module setup to change the way you want to optimise images.

Here is a link to the offical documentation https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/filter-image-optimize

Comment: Thank you very much sir @paj

Comment: @AlainStout if the answer was useful to you please accept the answer so it may be of use to others too.

Comment: Understand what you are saying, so far didn't succeed to turn it off also not with the documentation, watch the edited post with a print screen of the images not showing, the ?PageSpeed=off did succeed

Comment: If you do not administer the server / web server then you need to speak to the person that does and ask them to either disable or change the pagespeed module configuration for your site.

Comment: Hello @paj yes it succeeded , by going to the whm, easyapache4, have uninstalled mod_pagespeed from apache modules, thank you